# BASH-Calculate average of certain fields in same row

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a file with this format:
`

```
123456789 Lee Johnson 72 85 90
999999999 Jaime Smith 90 92 91
888111818 JC Forney 100 81 97
290010111 Terry Lee 100 99 100
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82
928441032 Jess Forester 85 80 82
928441032 Chris Forester 97 94 89`
```

I need to write a bash script to calculate each students' average grades(field 4-6), then output as such: 
`

```
71 [299226663] Camp Laney
80 [434401929] Camp Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp Tracey
93 [928441032] Forester Chris
82 [928441032] Forester Jess
92 [888111818] Forney JC
82 [123456789] Johnson Lee
99 [290010111] Lee Terry
91 [999999999] Smith Jaime`
```

The average is first field(truncated value), userid in brackets[], then  sorting order is as follows: last name(3rd field in org. file), then first name(2nd field in org. file), followed by userid(1st field in org. file)

NOTE: I already wrote a script to do this using awk but I'm supposed to do it a second time W/O awk or Perl. The tricky thing for me is being able to compute specific fields on the SAME row, then output the correct format. How would I do this?

Here is the solution using awk as a reference: 
`awk '{sum = $4 + $5 + $6; avg = sum/3;print int(avg), "[" $1 "]", $3, $2}' $1 | sort -k3 -k4 -k2`

Comment: "I already wrote a script to do this using awk but I'm supposed to do it a second time W/O awk or Perl." Tell your instructor that there is less than nothing to be gained from this exercise and perhaps Fortran, APL, INTERCAL, or DOS Batch would be better implementation languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` in bash will split the rows for you and allow a solution analogous to your awk version.

> One line is read from the standard input, and the first word is assigned to the first name, the second word to the second name, and so on, with leftover words and their intervening separators assigned to the last name.

```
$ cat rs.sh
while read -r id first last s1 s2 s3
do
    avg=$(((s1 + s2 + s3) / 3))
    printf "%d [%s] %s %s\n" $avg $id "$last" "$first";
done

$ cat rs.txt
123456789 Lee Johnson 72 85 90
999999999 Jaime Smith 90 92 91
888111818 JC Forney 100 81 97
290010111 Terry Lee 100 99 100
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82
928441032 Jess Forester 85 80 82
928441032 Chris Forester 97 94 89

$ sh rs.sh < rs.txt | sort -k3 -k4 -k2
71 [299226663] Camp Laney
80 [434401929] Camp Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp Tracey
93 [928441032] Forester Chris
82 [928441032] Forester Jess
92 [888111818] Forney JC
82 [123456789] Johnson Lee
99 [290010111] Lee Terry
91 [999999999] Smith Jaime
```

Comment: That's cool that you can split the rows and create variables like that. Does `read` have a default delimiter like some of the other bash commands? Do you need to specify the delimiter? I believe a space is used in my example file. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: For that you can set `IFS`. E.g.: `echo cat:dog:rabbit | (IFS=: read -r a b c; echo $c)`.

Comment: Instead of having a separate script into which you're feeding the file contents, you could also read in the file directly if you include `cat $1 | sort -k3,3 -k2,2 | while read ...` at the beginning of the while loop

Comment: I believe @jas just copied his commands/output from terminal to show the difference in outputs(why he cats the file). I just did this: `done< $1 | sort -k3 -k4 -k2`